# RewriteRule not working on password protected directory in Opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the opencart rewriterule to create seo friendly url's, so it creates me a .htaccess with the following in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emailer/
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So far, so good. But I also have a folder called 'protected' that i want to allow access to. This is ok as it doesn't rewrite directories, but I also want to password protect this folder server side, so cPanel automatically creates another .htaccess within the 'protected' folder with the following:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "emailer"
AuthUserFile "/home/mywebsite/.htpasswds/public_html/protected/passwd"
require valid-user
```

As soon as this .htaccess is created the first .htaccess won't allow the folder exception and every time I try to visit the password protected folder it gives me a 'page not found' error.

Do I need to enter anything else in the second .htaccess to make it work?

Comment: I don't see how your original rules exclude the `/protected/` folder at all

Comment: From what I've read, the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d is fine for any direct access to a directory. I know for a fact the admin folder is absolutely fine.